# Replace only if string after some string

Tags: php, regex, encoding, replace

Background is I want to **encode emails** from `user@domain.com` to `user#domain@com`

```
$email = 'user@domain.com';
$email_encode = str_replace( '@' , '#' , $email ); // user#domain.com
$email_encode = str_replace( '.' , '@' , $email_encode ); // user#domain@com
```

This should be done right ? But if `user`is something like `hello.world`

It will get `hello@world#domain@com`, so **this is wrong**.

It **should be** `hello.world#domain@com`

---

**So question is :**

How to replace `dot` if `dot` after `#` ?

This question is open for another better solution like regex or something else.

*(I will use on my own risk)*

---

Comment: The regular expression for this pattern is trivial. Did you try constructing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like

```
^(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)$
```

and replace with `$1#$2@$3`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR4nW7/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the last...
- `@`  - an at sign
- `(.*)` - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the last ...
- `\.` - literal dot
- `(.*)` -  Group 3 capturing the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: `preg_replace( '/^(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)$/' , '$1#$2@$3', 'hello.world@domain.com' );` , Thanks so much